# How to seperate by loose parts without blender freezing and crashing?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Trying to get my single object to split into multiple by using "by loose parts" but as soon as I click it, blender freezes.(I've let it sit and run for 8 hours and still hasn't worked) it has a ton of geometry (over 3 million on all) but even when I just select a few thousand vert, faces, and edges it still freezes

Comment: It most likely means your hardware is too low end to allow Blender to work on that amount of geometry; probably OS is trying to swap as many resources as possible on hard disk hence it freezes but it doesn't help in the end. Without more details about your hardware and OS you use it's probably the only thing which can be claimed with certainty

Comment: I'm suing an i5, gtx960 on windows 10.

Comment: You can try to roughly select half mesh, press Ctrl L to select linked, P to separate selected vertices, and then separate each half by loose parts, allowing Blender suffer half.